# What's taken as a base case in induction involving all integers.

Tags: group-theory, induction

I am trying to prove for groups

$$(g^n)^{-1} = g^{-n} \quad\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

I am thinking of using induction to prove it.Usually simple induction would require taking the base case as $g(0)$, but here, as I am talking about all integers, I am confused about what my base case will be.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Take $0$ as the base case to prove it for all non-negative integers.  Then prove it for negative integers separately

Comment: oh okay that makes sense. But again, what would be the base case for negative integers?

Comment: You can reuse $0$.

Comment: Reformulate the statement for negative integers to a statement about positive integers

Comment: doesn't base case have to be the smallest number ? For negative integers wouldn't 0 be the largest case , would that work too?

Comment: Hmm reformulate... could you elaborate ? I am not going anywhere with what i've tried

Comment: You can do induction where you "step" any increment you want.  Your induction case is to prove of $P(n)\implies P(n-1)$.  If you prove $P(0)$ is true; and $P(n)\implies P(n-1)$ then you have proven it is true fo all $n \in \mathbb Z^-$.

Comment: ...or... you could state your $P(n)$  as  "something is true for $-n$".....

Comment: Induction isn't magic.

Comment: yea maybe i wasn't so clear about it being like that

Answer (score 1):

Can you prove using induction that $(g^n)^{-1}=g^{-n}$ for all $n\ge0$ and $(g^{-n})^{-1}=g^n$ for all $n\ge0$?

Since $n=-(-n)$, that would prove that $(g^n)^{-1}=g^{-n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Makes sense , i'll give it a try i guess?